# How can I define Prolog rule to achieve bidirectional query?

Tags: prolog

I have defined

```
double(X,Y) :- Y is X*2.
```

and when I query `double(3,Y)`, I get `Y=6`.

But when I query `double(X,6),` I cannot get `X=3`.

Is it possible to define a rule that works in both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to check which of the variables is not yet set, and act accordingly. A skeleton code, without error checking:

```
double(X,Y) :-  % Y = 2*X
  (  var(X) ->
      (  var(Y) -> freeze(X, double(X,Y)),
                   freeze(Y, double(X,Y))
      ;  X is Y/2
      )
  ;  Y is 2*X
  ).
```

Which gives us, in SWI Prolog,

```
33 ?- double(3,6).
true.

34 ?- double(3,Y).
Y = 6.

35 ?- double(X,6).
X = 3.

36 ?- double(X,Y).
freeze(X, double(X, Y)),
freeze(Y, double(X, Y)).

37 ?- double(X,Y),Y=6.
X = 3,
Y = 6.

38 ?- double(X,Y),X=3.
X = 3,
Y = 6.

39 ?- double(X,Y),X=3,Y=41.
false.
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
41 ?- use_module( library(clpfd)).
true.

42 ?- [user].
double(X,Y):- Y #= X * 2.
```

to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X),            Y is X * 2 .
double(X,Y) :-            nonvar(Y), X is Y / 2 .
```

Though that does leave you with the possibility of getting 2 solutions when both arguments are instantiated (`double(3,1.5).` will succeed twice).

You could fix that in a number of ways:

- Using a cut to eliminate the extraneous choice point.

  ```
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X),            Y is X * 2 , ! .
  double(X,Y) :-            nonvar(Y), X is Y / 2     .
  ```
- Adding an additional type check.

  ```
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X),    var(Y), Y is X * 2 .
  double(X,Y) :-            nonvar(Y), X is Y / 2 .
  ```
- Or more:

  ```
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X), nonvar(Y), X =:= Y .
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X),    var(Y), Y is X * 2 .
  double(X,Y) :-    var(X), nonvar(Y), X is Y / 2 .
  ```

  If you went that route, one could add a 4th case, if you wanted, that would produce an infinite sequence of numbers and their doubles:

  ```
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X), nonvar(Y), X =:= Y .
  double(X,Y) :- nonvar(X),    var(Y), Y is X * 2 .
  double(X,Y) :-    var(X), nonvar(Y), X is Y / 2 .
  double(X,Y) :-    var(X),    var(Y), between(0,infinity), Y is X * 2.
  ```